# How to free up memory when saving images inside IndexDB

Tags: angularjs-directive, browser-cache, indexeddb

I have a no of images on page and trying to save it inside IndexDb if it does not exist.
All seems to be working fine and images load up instantly if it exist but looks like browser memory is leaking. It's give some jerk and hang sometime. I m not sure how this can be handle, I have written a directive that looks like this

```
 (function () {
            'use strict';

            // TODO: replace app with your module name
            angular.module('app').directive('imageLocal', imageLocal);

            imageLocal.$inject = ['$timeout', '$window', 'config', 'indexDb'];

            function imageLocal($timeout, $window, config, indexDb) {
                // Usage:
                // 
                // Creates:
                // 
                var directive = {
                    link: link,
                    restrict: 'A'
                };
                return directive;

                function link(scope, element, attrs) {

                    var imageId = attrs.imageLocal;
                    // Open a transaction to the database
                    var transaction;

                    $timeout(function () {
                        transaction = indexDb.db.transaction(["mystore"], "readwrite");
                        getImage();

                    }, 500);

                    function getImage() {

                        transaction.objectStore('mystore').get(imageId)
                            .onsuccess = function (event) {

                                var imgFile = event.target.result;

                                if (imgFile == undefined) {
                                    saveToDb(imgFile);
                                    return false;
                                }

                                showImage(imgFile);
                            }
                    }

                    function showImage(imgFile) {
                        console.log('getting');
                        // Get window.URL object
                        var url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;

                        // Create and revoke ObjectURL
                        var imageUrl = url.createObjectURL(imgFile);
                        element.css({
                            'background-image': 'url("' + imageUrl + '")',
                            'background-size': 'cover'
                        });


                    }

                    function saveToDb() {

                        // Create XHR
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                        blob;

                        xhr.open("GET", config.remoteServiceName + '/image/' + imageId, true);
                        // Set the responseType to blob
                        xhr.responseType = "blob";

                        xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
                            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                                console.log("Image retrieved");
                                // Blob as response
                                blob = xhr.response;
                                console.log("Blob:" + blob);

                                // Put the received blob into IndexedDB
                                putInDb(blob);
                            }
                        }, false);
                        // Send XHR
                        xhr.send();


                        function putInDb(blob) {

                            // Open a transaction to the database
                            transaction = indexDb.db.transaction(["mystore"], "readwrite");

                            // Put the blob into the database
                            var request = transaction.objectStore("mystore").add(blob, imageId); 
                            getImage();

                            request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                                console.log('saved');

                            }
                        };
                    }
                }
            }

        })();
```

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, how are you seeing that the browser is leaking memory?